# Airline Reservation System Which destination has more than 2 flight in a day?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I want to get result showing:

Which destination has more than 1 flight in a day from Istanbul?

I have `flightIDs`, `departureairport(ISTANBUL)`, `flightdates` in the columns.

```
SELECT reservation.flightID,departureairport,flightdate
FROM Flight INNER JOIN reservation ON reservation.FlightID = flight.FlightID
WHERE departureairport like "ISTANBUL"
GROUP BY departureairport,flightdate,reservation.flightID;
```

How can I select the day that has more than 1 flight???

Comment: I don't understand completely. Yesterday there may have been two flights to Rome and two to Paris, and the day before three flights to Paris and on a day a year before two flights to Rome. So do you want a list of these two destinations? Or of the three dates? Or of the four date-destination pairs? Or what else?

Comment: With SQL questions you should always tag the DBMS used. Why do you use `LIKE` with a string containing no pattern, by the way? Do you mean `WHERE departureairport = 'ISTANBUL'`? (String literals should always be in single quotes.) Or were you trying to do something special by applying `LIKE` instead of `=`? If so, what? And what does a `reservation` have to do with the task given? (It's in your query, but I don't know why.)